# SQL - reuse partition by window function with different filter condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, window, partition-by

I have a table `orders` with the following fields:

```
order_id: varchar
user_id:  varchar
item_id:  varchar
datetime: timestamp
quantity: int
```

The following query would help me find the last item by each user_id where the quantity is > 10.

```
WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY datetime DESC)
    FROM orders
    WHERE quantity > 10
)
SELECT user_id, item_id, datetime FROM ranked where rn = 1
```

Now, instead of considering orders with quantity > 10, I want to find the same information but with different thresholds, like 20, 50, 100.

One option is to have another 3 different queries, one for each threshold. However, it looks not efficient. Is there a better query?

Thanks.

P/S: I will need one for SparkSQL or Postgres. However, generic SQL is fine.

Comment: Use a case expression to define groups to partition by, Having sample data and expected results to work with would be useful.

Comment: You are worried about efficiency even though you don't know how long it takes in the first place?